# Is there a way to determine that a .a or .so library has been compiled as position indepenent code?

Tags: gcc, position, fpic

I am getting a linking error when compiling the numpy library against lapack indicating I need to compile lapack with -fPIC.  I thought I had done just that.  Is there a way to determine that the produced lapack library is position independent?

Comment: possible duplicate, but no answer there seems to be correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell, with something like objdump, if an object file has been built with -fPIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wi)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In general, you have no way of knowing:

```
$ cat a.c
int foo(int x) { return x+1; }
$ gcc -fno-pic a.c -c -o nopic.o
$ gcc -fPIC a.c -c -o pic.o   
$ cmp pic.o nopic.o 
$ cmp pic.o nopic.o && echo Identical
Identical
```

Comment: Not a representative example.

Answer (score 21):

You may have some luck with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wit/1351771#1351771), although it's platform dependent and doesn't work for all object files (but if you code manipulates pointers in any way, it should work).

This is the result of `objdump -r` on a file compiled with `-fPIC`:

```
test.o:     file format elf32-i386

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
00000007 R_386_PC32        __i686.get_pc_thunk.cx
0000000d R_386_GOTPC       _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

and this is for a file without PIC:

```
test.o:     file format elf32-i386
```