# Given an object file, can I see what compiler flags were used to build it?

Tags: linux, gcc

Given a .a or .so library, or a .o object file, can I see what compiler flags were used to build it?

Where compiler flags differ between compilers, is there nevertheless any way to extract information about levels of optimization, targeted machine, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the compiler options from a compiled executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719/can-we-get-compiler-information-from-an-elf-binary)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276561/can-i-determine-which-compiler-linker-flags-where-used-to-create-a-binary-only-s

Comment: From that answer: "it won't work for executables compiled without that option."